# Record has multiple statuses that gets rechecked. Only want records that meet a certain criteria

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table like below

```
Account number |  Last Name  |   Status       |   date
111                doe           acknowledged   04-11-2013
111                doe           acknowledged   05-01-2013
111                doe           paid           05-10-2013
123                smith         acknowledged   05-15-2013
123                smith         acknowledged   05-22-2013
145                walter        paid           05-23-2013
```

There are names and account numbers that holder the same information but just have different statuses and dates.

I am trying to get the most recent date and compare it to the current date. So for today I would compare doe with 5-10, smith with 5-22 and walter with 5-23...

Now an account can get rechecked multiple times and it will only stop getting rechecked once it has been paid. So smith would be the only one to get recheck at a later date.

I am wanting to find all of the records that have an acknowledged status. I do not want any of these to be paid.

So far in my code I able to get the max date for a record, but it brings back the acknowledged and the paid record since they are both distinct. I only want records that have not been paid and that are still acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the most recent acknowledged status for accounts that are not paid.  Here is a query for that:

```
select AccountNumber, Name,
       max(date)
from t
group by AccountNumber, Name
having sum(case when status = 'Paid' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

You only have the two different statuses in your question.  If you had more and you wanted just the acknowledged max date, then you would do:

```
select AccountNumber, Name,
       max(case when status = 'Acknowledged' then date end)
from t
group by AccountNumber, Name
having sum(case when status = 'Paid' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

To get the most recent status, you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows:

```
select AccountNumber, Name,
       max(case when status = 'Acknowledged' then date end),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as MostRecentStatus
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by AccountNumber, Name order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by AccountNumber, Name
having sum(case when status = 'Paid' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: that fixed my problem, how would I still be able to include the status column though. If i include it with the aggregate function then I will have to group by 'status' and that's when it will choose acknowledged again even if it's been paid. So far it is displaying what I want it to but only the date, I would like the 'status' and the date next to each other if possible. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2046032 . . . The OP only has two statuses and you are taking out `paid`.  So, `'Acknolwedged' as status` in the `select` should do the trick.

Comment: lets say I had other statuses i wanted to include, like 'Pending' and 'Error' I would run the same query with the updated statuses, like this 


select account_number,
  lastname,
       max(case when status = 'Acknowledged' or status = 'Pending' or status = 'Error' then date end)
from t
group by account_number, lastname
having sum(case when status = 'Paid' then 1 else 0 end) = 0


but then I still can't associate the status with the correct name if I just have that 'acknowledged' paceholder column

Comment: I just did a union with the same criteria and changed 'acknowledged' to 'pending' and it seemed to work. Would this be the best method?

Comment: @user2046032 . . . The `row_number()` method is likely to be more efficient.  If the `union` method works for you then great.  You should be using `union all` for performance reasons.

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you have the time could you tell me how I would implement the row_number() member in this? The unions work, but it takes around 4 minutes to run...

Comment: @user2046032 . . . The last example in the answer uses `row_number()`.